# Suddely files started missing from Wordpress and showing errors

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My domain: bharahobe.info

I have installed WordPress in main domain and sydney theme. Everything was okay. Suddenly when I visit my site it shows error messages. Like this:

> Warning: require(/home/bharahob/public_html/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/bharahob/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 102
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/bharahob/public_html/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/bharahob/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 102

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access through FTP or SSH, you should log into the server and verify that those files exist. The files may have been deleted by a bot or botched upgrade. The permissions may have changed as well.

If the files are actually missing, you can probably get away with downloading the version of WP you're currently running and replace the missing files.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me why these files actually deleted and how can I restrict them from being deleted?

Comment: Not without doing some investigation. If you're on a host that automatically updates WP for you, the update may have failed. File permissions could have changed and those files weren't available. There are too many possibilities to say for sure. 

I would recommend doing some Googling and seeing if you can determine the cause. If you have the option of using git on your host, I would recommend setting up a repo on github or bitbucket to keep your site backed up and properly versioned. This way if anything changes, you can easily revert back to the last working version.